# Unable to manually save changes to RavenDB docs

Tags: database, nosql, ravendb

I have a RavenDB hosted on IIS.I am not able to modify/change RavenDB documents manually/directly in the ravendb studio? For example, if I want to change a field value from 1 to 2, 
and try to save the document, its not closing the document pop up 
screen and its not saving the document changes.

I checked the RavenDB folder, the web/data folder - and unchecked the 
read only check box, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you look with Fiddler what response do you get from the server?

Comment: I am unable to get fiddler to work.. any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config file in RavenDB had to be changed to allow anonymous write access. The change is from

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/>
```

to

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/>
```